# Marklogic: cts:and-query searching the same node for two attributes

Tags: marklogic

I want to do `cts:and-query` for two attributes in the same node.  `cts:and-query` is searching for test condition in the document seperately rather than in same node.

Is there a way to restrict search to apply on the same node?

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the and-query inside an element-query as described in the second example here:

http://docs.marklogic.com/cts:element-query?q=cts:element-query

It doesn't necessary limit to the direct element itself, also descendants are included in the match, but depending on your content structure this might be sufficient.

If not, use an XPath predicate to filter out false positives from search results. Makes counting search totals etc more difficult, but at least gives right results.

HTH!

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your XML structure, you may be able to do this by using a `cts:near-query()` with a distance of zero, instead of using a `cts:and-query()`. I wrote a post while ago that talks about [near-query distance](http://blog.davidcassel.net/2012/08/a-trick-with-ctsnear-query/). In short, distance depends on words inside of elements, but isn't affected by words in attributes. This should do the trick:

```
cts:near-query(
  (cts:element-attribute-value-query($element-qname, $attr1-qname),
   cts:element-attribute-value-query($element-qname, $attr2-qname)),
  0
)
```

Note that this approach won't work if there aren't `element-level` words separating the attributes of one element from those of another element. For example:

```
<doc>
  <stuff a="1" b="2">some text</stuff>
  <stuff a="3" b="4">some other text</stuff>
</doc>
```

The text inside of the stuff elements provides some distance between `/doc/stuff\[1\]`'s attributes and `/doc/stuff\[2\]`'s attributes. There is no distance between the a and b attributes. If the stuff element has no text, then there will not be distance between `/doc/stuff\[1\]`'s attributes and `/doc/stuff\[2\]`'s attributes.